# How to count elements inside a text field

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my PostgreSQL DB, I have a table with a field of the type text which contains a string like this:

```
|ABX1-001|ABX1-002|ABX1-004|ABX1-005|
```

I would like to count the items inside the text field `current_ids`.
This is the structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."candidates" (
    "day" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "study_id" varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    "site_id" varchar(32),
    "status" varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    "total" int4 NOT NULL,
    "current" int4 NOT NULL,
    "referrer_token" varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NO_REFERRER_TOKEN'::character varying,
    "total_ids" text NOT NULL DEFAULT '|'::text,
    "current_ids" text NOT NULL DEFAULT '|'::text
);
```

Some sample data:

| 2020-01-01 00:00:00+00 | ABX1 | USA-1 | INCOMPLETE | 4 | 4 | NO_REFERRER_TOKEN | |ABX1-001|ABX1-002|ABX1-004|ABX1-004| |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00+00 | ABX1 | USA-1 | INCOMPLETE | 9 | 7 | NO_REFERRER_TOKEN | |ABX1-009|ABX1-010|ABX1-011|ABX1-012|ABX1-013|ABX1-014|ABX1-016|ABX1-018|ABX1-020| |

Comment: Please [post data as text, not a painting of it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)! In particular, post the SQL code that we can use to re-create the schema and table rows.

Comment: 1) `select array_length(string_to_array(trim('|ABX1-001|ABX1-002|ABX1-004|ABX1-005|', '|'), '|'), 1); 4` 2) `select count(*) from  string_to_table(trim('|ABX1-001|ABX1-002|ABX1-004|ABX1-005|', '|'), '|'); 4`.

Answer (score 2):

First off storing a delimited list of related ids is an extremely bad plan. As pointed out by @ErwinBrandstetter a normalized form and creating a separate table with a row for each related id is a much, much better approach. However since you want only the number of related ids:  

Providing the string is guaranteed to begin and end with the delimiter then you only need 2 simple string functions: `replace()` and `length()`. Use replace to remove the delimiters. Then difference in the resulting string length gives the number of delimiters removed. Since there is a delimiter at the start and at the end of string the number of delimiters removed is 1 greater then the number of elements. So the resulting number of related is: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/EG1ms60B))

```
select length(total_ids) - length( replace(total_ids,'|', '')) - 1 "total ids"
  from candidates;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using functions from here [String functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) and function from here [Array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html):

```
select array_length(string_to_array(trim('|ABX1-001|ABX1-002|ABX1-004|ABX1-005|', '|'), '|'), 1);

 array_length 
--------------
            4
```

The `trim` function removes the leading and trailing `|` and then `string_to_array` splits the string on the remaining `|` to produce a single dimension text array. The `array_length` function then counts the number of elements in the 1 array dimension.

Alternate:

```
select count(*) from  string_to_table(trim('|ABX1-001|ABX1-002|ABX1-004|ABX1-005|', '|'), '|');
```

The `trim` does the same thing and then `string_to table` produces a table with each element in a row which then counted using `count`.

Answer (score 1):

That all depends.
**If** we can rely on a fixed length of 8 characters per key and 1 character per separator, then **integer division** is a very simple & fast way:

```
SELECT *, length(total_ids) / 9 AS current_ids_count
FROM   candidates;
```

[Integer division](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html) truncates, so leading and dangling noise doesn't matter as long as it stays below 9 characters total.

**If** the length can vary, but we can rely on the separator `|` (and no leading or dangling white space), then consider [Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver)'s solutions.

Typically, it's best to store such data as actual array, or in [normalized form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) as separate table with n:1 relationship to `candidates` to begin with.

Comment: You are right about normalization but the table was decided in this way, not from me. I cannot change that behavior at the moment. 
One of my teammates told me an ID max will look like this 'ANON1-000001'.